# How to access files on a zfs pool of which only the vdev is left?

Tags: zfs, file-recovery, sparsefile

I set up a zfs pool `mypool` with one sparse file as vdev. After a system crash only the undamaged vdev is left. Is there any chance to get files and folders out of it? I don't care to create another pool, currently I would have to force the creation because `zpool create` says that the sparse file is still part of `mypool`.

I'm using ubuntu-zfs 0.6.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 amd64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zpool import` is the right command for that (attention: `man zpool` contains two sections for `zpool import`, so don't skip reading after the first and thing that's what `zpool import` can do, like me...).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462859/how-to-mount-zfs-pools-created-on-a-different-disk might addresses the exact same problem.